# Give a molecule, how do we determine the serial number of each atom in it to put in a pdb file?

Tags: cheminformatics

Example:

For molecule of 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene, using RDKit's `MolToPDBFile()` function, I can convert this molecule to the pdb file shown below.

```
MODEL        1
HETATM    1  C1  UNL     1      -0.155   1.178  -0.139  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    2  C2  UNL     1       1.202   1.142  -0.326  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    3  C3  UNL     1       1.836  -0.081  -0.343  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    4  C4  UNL     1       1.109  -1.240  -0.174  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    5  C5  UNL     1      -0.255  -1.180   0.011  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    6  C6  UNL     1      -0.900   0.033   0.031  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM    7  N1  UNL     1      -2.307   0.122   0.221  1.00  0.00           N1+
HETATM    8  O1  UNL     1      -2.865   1.224   0.234  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM    9  O2  UNL     1      -3.070  -1.007   0.392  1.00  0.00           O1-
HETATM   10 CL1  UNL     1       3.569  -0.109  -0.582  1.00  0.00          CL  
HETATM   11  H1  UNL     1      -0.657   2.138  -0.125  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM   12  H2  UNL     1       1.780   2.067  -0.459  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM   13  H3  UNL     1       1.588  -2.220  -0.184  1.00  0.00           H  
HETATM   14  H4  UNL     1      -0.875  -2.066   0.149  1.00  0.00           H  
CONECT    1    2    2    6   11
CONECT    2    3   12
CONECT    3    4    4   10
CONECT    4    5   13
CONECT    5    6    6   14
CONECT    6    7
CONECT    7    8    8    9
END
ENDMDL
```

However, I do not understand how does it determine which carbon to start with. I thought there is an algorithm or rule behind, but I have not yet found any clue after 1hr of searching on google.

Any idea or suggestion about where I may find answer?

Comment: There are IUPAC naming rules. Then again, why bother? A PDB file with incorrect numbering is as good as any other.

Comment: I want to analyze a group of molecules(more than 50). Each of them has an atom of interest that seemingly always listed at the same order across all pdb files related. Now i want to run an analysis software using script and this idea can only work if I can confirm that those atoms would always have the same serial numbers across all my molecules, or at least I know how to calculate the serieal numbers they would belong to.

Comment: Then they probably adhere to the said rules. Not sure if it is strictly enforced, though.

Comment: yeah, that's where I get confused about, I have read a couple of articles discussing about format of pdb file, but none of them mentioned how exactly do they determine the serial number for each atom....

Comment: @Yuuya It is not yet evident why *the* atom of interest must show up on the same line of each file for your analysis. For instance in a [Kabsch test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) to compare conformations of one molecule, the relative position of an atom surrounded by other atoms is more important. By default, the [implementation](https://github.com/charnley/rmsd) by Charnley *et al.* addresses the issue of atoms' sequence in a xyz file by the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm); i.e. to retain *atom type*, but disregard an *atom label*.

Comment: it is not a conclusion but rather an observation, that's why I would like to bring this up for discussion. what i noticed was that atoms with similar relative structure/position seems to have same serial number as other atoms from other molecules, but i have no clue/reference to assert this is true.. @Buttonwood

Comment: @Yuuya Internally, RDKit's bookkeeping of atoms might (to some degree) rely on *atom indices*, integers starting by `0`.  You may visualize them (see for instance RDKit's entry in the [cookbook](http://rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#include-an-atom-index)).  One may argue once assigned, the report to pdb first states C, N, O, Cl (increasing atomic number) and eventually H (the report of [explicit] hydrogen atoms in a pdb is not mandatory).

Comment: @Buttonwood can you confirm if pdb file would inherit this rule when being converted from a mol object using rdkit?

Comment: You know that "p" in pdb is protein? This format isn't designed for some random stuff. And the number is largely arbitrary, it can be even negative.

Comment: @Yuuya The sequence of C-N-O-Cl is specific to your file. Try `from rdkit import Chem; smi = "c1ccncc1"; mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi); Chem.MolToPDBFile(mol, 'test.pdb')` about pyridine, and move N (e.g. describe py as `c1ccccn1`).  Vary now with explicit hydrogens in `from rdkit import Chem; smi = "c1ccccn1"; mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi); mol = Chem.AddHs(mol); Chem.MolToPDBFile(mol, 'test.pdb')`; hydrogens now included trail the non-H atoms. But rdkit and obabel report non-H in pdb in blocks, e.g. `c1ccccn1.c1cocc1` (a benzene and a furane), trailed by H. The sequence depends on the input.

Comment: @Yuuya And in similar tune to the comment by Mithoron: if you describe a small molecule, .mol/.sdf, or .mol2 are more suitable (if you don't need explicit coordinates, consider SMILES/SMARTS) than .pdb.  The later *can* be a container for small molecules, but pdb structures often contain a large protein + a couple of water molecules + one or a few small molecule ligand(s) + some cations / anions of the buffer used to isolate/crystallize the sample and hence the file format wants to retain these information and perhaps some comments, too.

Comment: @Yuuya To name `C1`, `C2`, `C3` *serial number* would be a bit unusual, though.  It is more common to describe them as *atom label*, and for convenience the element symbol typically is used as a part of the string.  Which differs from *atom type*, really about what element is meant (and in some file types, amended with additional information as if it is an alkyl carbon, an aromatic carbon, etc).

Answer (score 0):

> [OP] I thought there is an algorithm or rule behind, but I have not yet found any clue after 1hr of searching on google.

There is no [rule](https://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format). You have to rely on the "CONECT" records and the coordinates to find corresponding atoms.

In the example case, 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene, the presence of symmetry makes matching pairs of atoms in two molecules ambiguous. The way the carbon atoms are named, C3 is connected to the chloride and C6 is connected to the nitro groups (this is unexpected given the numbering in the name). C1 and C2 can be swapped for C5 and C4 without changing the connectivity. Also, naming of the two oxygen atoms is ambiguous.

If you want to find the best superposition of two 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene molecules, you have to consider these ambiguities and not rely on atoms with the same name matching.

If you are lucky and the files were generated by the same software, there might be some method in the naming madness. However, it is best not to rely on it but rather pair up atoms based on "CONECT" records and pairwise distances.